# Function not changing array

Tags: python, arrays, function, dictionary

```
ddx = []

def AGMA(): #anion gap metabolic acidosis

  ddx = ["Methanol", "Uremia", "Diabetic Ketoacidosis", "Paraldehyde", "Iron tablets", "Isoniazid", "Lactic acidosis", "Ethanol", "Salicylates (aspirin) - Late"]
  return ddx

print(ddx)
```

print(ddx) is just returning [] still

How do I get my function to actually change to the array I want?

Comment: How can your function "actually change to the array [you] want" when you don't even call the function itself? `ddx = AGMA()`

Comment: The `ddx` inside the function is a local variable and as nothing to do with the global one with the same name. You should pass it as an argument to `AGMA()`. isntead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the return value to the variable

```
ddx = AGMA()
```

Comment: Oh right!! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem! Thanks for asking